# Hibernate doesn't populate join table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one problem with Hibernate. I have classic **@ManyToMany** assosciation. When I insert data into tables, **join table is empty**.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "employee_interview", catalog = "db69824xmatko", schema = "",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "interview_id", nullable = false))
public Set<InterviewEntity> getInterviews() {
    return interviews;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "interviews")
    public Set<EmployeeEntity> getEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }
```

The code that I run is here:

```
InterviewEntity interviewEntity = prepareInterview();
        EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = prepareEmployeeEntity();
        employeeDao.create(employeeEntity);
        employeeEntity.getInterviews().add(interviewEntity);

        interviewEntity.getEmployees().add(employeeEntity);
        interviewDao.create(interviewEntity);
        interviewDao.flush();
        employeeDao.flush();
```

I tried to find any solution, but not successfully. I tried to flush(). SQL what I become without flush:

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    employee
    (created_date, created_user, first_name, last_name, login, password) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        interview
        (candidate_id, comment, created_date, created_user, interview_date, job, protocol, round) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

When I use flush SQL below is running:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        employee_interview
        (employee_id, interview_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

And I don't understand why I have empty table employee_interview when this SQL script was running. How I can fix this problem? How I can populate the join Table with the right data? Thanks for every hint. :)

When I create new employee everything is OK, but when I use old object then I have exception, that ID of interview after update not exists.

--UPDATE--
In...
    InterviewEntity interviewEntity = prepareInterview();

```
        EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = employeeDao.findById(11);
        employeeEntity.getInterviews().add(interviewEntity);//<<------------

        CandidateEntity candidateEntity = prepareCandidateEntity();

        interviewEntity.setCandidate(candidateEntity);
        interviewEntity.getEmployees().add(employeeEntity);//<<------------
        candidateDao.create(candidateEntity);
        interviewDao.create(interviewEntity);
        employeeDao.updateObject(employeeEntity);
```

and this code throw this exception

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.tuke.entity.InterviewEntity#104]
```

Comment: What's the difference in implementations between `employeeDao.flush()` and `interviewDao.flush()`?

Comment: You're adding the interview to the employee *after* you've saved the record.  You then add the employee to the interview before saving it, so their database state may be inconsistent.  Hibernate may be "helping" you out there.

Comment: no different between. is only Session.flush().

Comment: But why is in output insert into employee_interview when into table is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the relationship in InterviewEntity, too. Something like:

```
interviewEntity.getEmployees().add(employeeEntity)
```